# return List<object> from view of @Query in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am working with spring boot. I want to apply a **join** in **@Query** and get the results in List.

**objDto.java**

```
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class objDto {
    public int id;
    private String title;
}
```

**ObjDomain.java**

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ObjDomain implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    public String title;
}
```

**ShowDetailsRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface ShowDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<ObjDomain, Long> {
    @Query(value ="//JOIN QUERY HERE//", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ObjDto> showDetails();

}
```

My Join query is working well when I used it in **MYSQL CLI.**

> Error :   No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.example.com.data.transfer.objects.ObjDto]
>
> Expected Result : [{id: "1", title: "DEF"}]

Comment: how does your query look like?

Comment: https://www.roytuts.com/spring-boot-data-jpa-left-right-inner-and-cross-join-examples/

Please take a look at this. it may help

Answer (score 2):

You can create an interface projection instead of a DTO and in that interface you can only have the getter methods and pass that interface as the type of List.

```
@Query(value ="//JOIN QUERY HERE//", nativeQuery = true)
List<YourInterface> showDetails();
```

and your interface will look like this:

```
public interface YourInterface {
     int getid();
    String gettitle();
}
```

And make sure the getter methods in interface are in the same sequence as the values query results.

Comment: I am using an `DateTime getcreated_date()` in interface & respectively in **query** also. Using this DateTime I am getting the error (that I have comment above). If I omit the **date variable** then it shows me as per expectation result.
Please tell how to figure out this.

Comment: **Error :** Could not write JSON: Projection type must be an interface!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Projection type must be an interface! (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0] 
>com.sun.proxy.$Proxy211["created_date"])

Comment: In your interface, use `getcreatedDate` and in query use `select something, date(created_date) as createdDate, something` and make sure the alias names of your query matche with the ones in your interface.

Comment: it works fine for **Date var1** data type only. I need  **DateTime var1** . While I am trying to use **DateTime**  this gives the same error.

Comment: Can you make it return `Date` and then convert it to `DateTime` afterwards in your code? SQL seems to be in sync with `Date` only. That is because the datatype in your sql is `Date` and you're trying to return it in `DateTime`. One more option is to change the column type to `DateTime` in your SQL.

Comment: could you please update your answer according to your comment ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create sqlResultsetMapping..by doing that you are telling the sql in which class you want map the resultset. And also u can create the projection with help of interface. which can take less efforts compare to sqlResultsetMapping.

Below is the example

Lets say i want fetch few data from multiple table using native join query.
For Example- i will have to fetch empname and his dept from emp and dept table so my native query looks like below:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e.name as empName,d.name as deptName FROM emp e left join dept d on d.empid=e.id WHERE e.id=:Id ,nativeQuery = true)
 List<CustomData> findByRestaurantMenuGrouping(@Param("menuId") Long menuId);
```

Now put below resultsetmapping  above any entity i can either emp or dept.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "customDataMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = CustomData.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "empName", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "deptName", type = String.class),
                }
        )
)
```

-And  create CustomData class as response class with 2 fields and parameterized constructer.
After you can call query using entitymanager by providing resultsetmapping which we created above.

```
List<CustomData> customdata= (List<CustomData>) em.createNativeQuery(quiStringBuilder.toString().trim(), "customDataMapping").getResultList();
```

Comment: could you please update your answer with the code which i need to use Sir

Answer (score 0):

You should use the combine of annotation SqlResultSetMapping and NamedNativeQuery.

For example:

In your entity:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
            name = "ObjDtoMapping",
            classes = @ConstructorResult(
                    targetClass = objDto.class,
                    columns = {
                            @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "title")
            }
       )
  )
})
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "showDetails", query = "SELECT a.id, a.title from 
 ObjDomain a", resultSetMapping = "ObjDtoMapping")
public class ObjDomain implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    public String title;
}
```

And then, in your repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ShowDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<ObjDomain, Long> {
    @Query(name ="showDetails", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ObjDto> showDetails();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

change `List<ObjDto>` to

```
List<Object[]>
```

then in Service layer

```
List<Object[]> objectList = repositoryObj.showDetails();

for (Object[] obj : objectList) {

 //.......
}
```